# Connect to mongoDB socket in Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, sockets, docker

I have a docker container that has Rails and mongoDB running in it.
I set the mongo configuration to use a unix socket for the connection because the only resource that really needs to connect to it (the rails app) is running in the container. 
Whenever I try to connect to the `mongo` shell I get this error:

> [main] Error: network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster'
>   on host '127.0.0.1:27017'

I have my mongoDB configuration set up like this:

```
#mongod.conf - 3.4
    storage:
        dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb"
        directoryPerDB: true
        journal:
            enabled: true
    systemLog:
        destination: file
        path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log"
        logAppend: true
        timeStampFormat: iso8601-utc
    processManagement:
        fork: true
    net:
        bindIp: 127.0.0.1
        port: 27017
        wireObjectCheck: false
        unixDomainSocket:
            enabled: true
    net:
      ssl:
        mode: requireSSL
        PEMKeyFile: /etc/ssl/certs/db/mongodb.pem


    security:
      authorization: enabled
```

Has anyone else run into this issue as well? Is there a best practice on mongoDB configuration within docker containers?

Answer (score 2):

You might need to give which docker image you are using to start with, and if it isn't a mongo centric container, how is mongo being installed and started?

If you are not using the official image here:
https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/
you might try adding your application to it for debugging purposes

e.g.

```
FROM mongo

# System ruby
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
curl ruby \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN bash -l -c 'ruby -v'

# Or Get a new version of ruby
ENV GET_RUBY ruby-2.3.3

RUN curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
RUN bash -c 'source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh && rvm install $GET_RUBY && rvm use --default $GET_RUBY'
RUN bash -l -c 'ruby -v'
add . /assets
```

Also, as a best practice you should not have the mongo service inside your application container.  Instead, fire up the official one and utilize it from your other container, here is a docker-compose.yml from a project I use that has mongo in it:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
  web:
    build: .
    command: npm start
    volumes:
      - .:/meanshop
    ports:
      - "7000:7000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      PORT: 7000
      MONGODB_DB_URL: "mongodb://db/meanshop"
```